# z3c.form and Javascript subform CRUD widget for Plone

Tags: plone, z3c.form

I need a widget which has add/remove of subforms via Javascript (create-read-update-delete).

It would be similar to DataGridField, but instead of having lines it would present subforms as blocks.

A jQuery plug-in example: http://vipullimbachiya.com/jQuery/Plugins/MultiField/SampleMultiField.htm#example

Does z3c.form or Plone has this kind of subform CRUD widgets already? The main thing would be implement this 100% on the client side, without HTTP postback when you press add/remove buttons.

Answer (score 0):

There is [`plone.z3cform.crud`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.z3cform) / [`plone.app.z3cform.crud`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.z3cform):

```
class IOneEntry(interface.Interface):
    # Schema definition

class MainForm(crud.CrudForm):
    update_schema = IOneEntry

    def get_items(self):
        # return items implementing IOneEntry

    def add(self, data):
        # Add one IOneEntry object

    def remove(self, (id, data)):
        # Remove one IOneEntry object
```

but this does *not* use AJAX to add entries.

Comment: Any z3c.form widget which would render/input a form? Because I basically could get away with DataGridField having its only column having this special "SubformWidget"?

Comment: For one project we customized the data grid subform's template so that it is presented as a full form rather than a table row. So I'm pretty sure the javascript for adding/removing rows still works in that case. Our code isn't really in a reusable state, though, I'm afraid.